# Generic JNI Type instantiation

Tags: java, c++, generics, java-native-interface

How can I instanciate a generic type in c++?

If I want to create a `List<X>` where `X` is object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just instantiate List. As Generics are erased by the compiler, this is fully equivalent to List at runtime.

Comment: What about if my jni method needs to return a `Pair<Int, String>` is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Given you cannot instantiate a generic type at runtime in Java, I am pretty sure you can't do it in C++.

Generics are a compile time feature.  Unless you want to pass what you produce to a compiler e.g. as plain Java code in text, generics are unlikely to be useful to you.  (And if you did want to do this I suspect C++ wouldn't be your best choice)

> If I want to create a List where X is object

In Java `X` is a type of *reference* to an object. As the code from all Lists only hold references, the code is the same and is not templated like in C++.  This means you can't use a primitives or structs or objects, only references.

Comment: He doesn't want to instantiate X, he wants to instantiate List<X>.